# How can I AND two OR statements with the #states feature of Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, forms

This [page](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-form-api-using-states-multiple-conditionals-and-or-and-xor) explains nicely how to use OR with the #states feature. However, when I try to AND two OR statements, It doesn't seem to AND them together. Is there a way to do this? This is what I tried.

```
 'visible' => array(
    array(
      array(':input[name="vehicle"]' => array('value' => 'truck')),
      array(':input[name="vehicle"]' => array('value' => 'car')),
    ),
    array(
      array(':input[name="mileage"]' => array('value' => '10')),
      array(':input[name="mileage"]' => array('value' => '20')),
    ),

  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this can be done this way:

```
$form['non_phd_student'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    // This #states rule says that the "non_phd_student" item should only
    // be shown if the "student_type" form element is set to "Undergraduate" or "graduate".
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        array(
          array(':input[name="student_type"]' => array('value' => 'undergraduate')),
          array(':input[name="student_type"]' => array('value' => 'graduate')),
        )

      ),
    ),
);
$form['non_phd_student']['thanks'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#description' => t('Thanks for providing your graduate status and your country');
  '#states' => array(
  //Because this has ['non_phd_student']
  //The or in $form['non_phd_student'] is ANDed into the or of this statement.
  // Action to take: Make visible.
  'visible' => array(
    array(
      array(':input[name="school_country"]' => array('value' => t('Other'))),
      array(':input[name="school_country"]' => array('value' => 'UK')),
    )
  ),
),
);
```

There is another answer that takes more work. We can do this because AND statements can be inside the OR statements. Also, because of [Propositional Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) we can get the same results this way:

```
'visible' => array(
  array(
    array(
      ':input[name="vehicle"]' => array('value' => 'truck'),
      ':input[name="mileage"]' => array('value' => '10'),
    ),
    array(
      ':input[name="vehicle"]' => array('value' => 'truck'),
      ':input[name="mileage"]' => array('value' => '20'),
    ),
    array(
      ':input[name="vehicle"]' => array('value' => 'car'),
      ':input[name="mileage"]' => array('value' => '20'),
    ),
    array(
      ':input[name="vehicle"]' => array('value' => 'car'),
      ':input[name="mileage"]' => array('value' => '10'),

    ),
  ),

),
```